# Get unique count of related models with conditional statement

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I need to get a list of users who have made certain styles of recipes, a certain number of times.

Users have recipes, and recipes have sessions where they have been made.

Users can have many recipes and recipes can have many sessions.

Recipes have styles, and I am after users who have sessions for a particular set of styles. I am after a unique count though, not an overall count.

The recipes styles are '12C', '21A', '21B', '21BA', '21BB', '21BC', '21BD', '21BE', '21BF', '22A'.

In my case, I am after users who have made at least 3 different styles of recipe. So if a user has made 3 recipes; 2 of '12C' and one of '21A', then the query should not return them. But if a user has made 3 recipes; one each of '12C', '21A', and '21B', then they should be returned.

I drummed up the below which gets me a list of users who have 3 or more sessions of recipes matching the above styles, but it is not a unique count of those sessions, so a user who has made 3 recipes - 2 of '12C' and one of '21A' - is returned when they shouldn't be:

```
App\Models\User::whereHas('recipes', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('style_id', ['12C', '21A', '21B', '21BA', '21BB', '21BC', '21BD', '21BE', '21BF', '22A'])
            ->has('sessions');
    }, '>=', 3)
    ->get();
```

**What do I need to add, to allow the `whereHas` callback to only return unique records based on the `style_id`?**

Alternatively, could I use a collection retrieved from a similar query to the above and iterate over each user and reduce the recipe array down to just unique recipes based on the `style_id`:

```
\App\Models\User::whereHas('recipes', $callback)
    ->with(['recipes' => $callback])
    ->take(5)
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($user) {
        $user->recipes = $user->recipes->unique('style_id');
        return $user;
    });
```

This was my attempt at this, however the result of this still contains an array of recipes that have more than one recipe per `style_id`.

**Edit**

Here are my model definitions.

**User**

```
public function recipes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Recipe::class);
}
```

**Recipe**

```
public function sessions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Session::class);
}
```

Comment: which table have the style column, is it in receipe or session table?

Comment: The recipes table has the style column.

Comment: i think you can add `groupBy` in whereHas like this `$query->whereIn('style_id', ['12C', '21A', '21B', '21BA', '21BB', '21BC', '21BD', '21BE', '21BF', '22A'])
            ->has('sessions')->groupBy('style_id')`. it will always return you distinct row

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid by model definitions, do you just meaning the model relationships or are you asking for something else?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have added these now, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @James I might guess that in `whereHas` you could add `->select(DB::raw('count(distinct style_id)'))` and rest should same as it is, would give you count for distinct styles and later `'>= 3` will statisfy your criteria. Just a test give it a try

Comment: user must have atleast 3 unique receipe styles with session, is it? test my answer and let me know

Comment: @AkramWahid that is correct.

Comment: did you try my answer bellow? make sure `->havingRaw('COUNT(id) > ?', [2])` , id is same as your recipe table primary key

Answer (score 0):

please try this and let me know,

```
      \App\Models\User::withCount([
        'recipes' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereIn('style_id', ['12C', '21A', '21B', '21BA', '21BB', '21BC', '21BD', '21BE', '21BF', '22A'])
                ->groupBy('style_id')
                ->havingRaw('COUNT(id) > ?', [2])
                ->has('sessions');
        }
    ])->get();
```

**Edited**: added a filter to collection

```
 \App\Models\User::withCount([
'recipes' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('style_id', ['12C', '21A', '21B', '21BA', '21BB', '21BC', '21BD', '21BE', '21BF', '22A'])
        ->groupBy('style_id')
        ->havingRaw('COUNT(id) > ?', [2])
        ->has('sessions');
}
])
->get()
 ->filter(function ($user) {

    return $user->recipes_count > 2;
});
```

Comment: The query runs, however the `recipes_count` that I get back is null. I will verify whether the users returned are actually users that should be returned.

Comment: This query returns all users, not just the users that match the conditions.

Comment: does it return `recipes_count` correctly? surely it will return all users, we need to filter by `whereHas` then

Comment: I updated the answer, test it and let me know, but if you have a large no of data, i would advice to go with joining the table and get the count, instead of my method,

Answer (score 0):

Use a modified `withCount()`:

```
User::withCount(['recipes' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT style_id)'))
        ->whereIn('style_id', ['12C', '21A', '21B', '21BA', '21BB', '21BC', '21BD', '21BE', '21BF', '22A'])
        ->has('sessions');
}])->having('recipes_count', '>=', 3)->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?